# Android timestamp to local user time or date

Tags: java, android

how can i convert Timestamp to user local time or date what i mean or what i want
 its this result in image

[image: please edit and show image]

as image shown the time of every message from timestamp  if
been a long time its will convert with month name like `SEP 7 AT 2:40 PM`

AND more longer like

> JAN 14,2017 AT 4:38 PM

or its today be like

> 12:00 AM

or two days ago

> WED AT 12:00 AM

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: What do your timestamp currently look like? What code do you have at the moment? Also, look over http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Comment: @cricket_007 like this `1497714279`

Comment: Showing different formats requires if-else statements. There's no single solution for the logic applied to the date displayed after a certain time period

Comment: @cricket_007 please remove the duplicate i need different formats

Comment: Then read the documentation... Learn. It's all there

Comment: In other words, replacing `"YYYY-MM-dd"` to just display the hour/minutes isn't that difficult to figure out... If you're having problems with specific formats, post a new question that includes code you've tried.